# How to overcome an infinite loop?

Tags: r

I am totally new to R. Hopefully you can help. I am trying to simulate from a Hawkes process using R. The main idea is that-first of all I simulated some events from a homogeneous Poisson process. Then each of these events will create their own children using a non homogeneous Poisson process. The code is like as below:

```
 SimulateHawkesprocess<-function(n,tmax,lambda,lambda2){
         times<-Simulatehomogeneousprocess(n,lambda)
         count<-1
         while(count<n){
             newevent<-times[count] +      Simulateinhomogeneousprocess(lambda2,tmax,lambdamax=NA)
             times<-c(times,newevent)
             count<-count+1
             n<-length(times)
             }
          return(times)
    }
```

But the r code is producing this infinite loop(probably because of the last line: (n<-length(times))). How can I overcome this problem? How can I put a stopping condition?

Comment: where is `Simulateinhomogeneousprocess` defined?

Comment: How many times do you want the loop to run? You have a stopping condition - when count is not less than n - your problem is that you adjust n and count. Deleting the line `n <- length(times)` would result in a loop that stops, but who knows what you want?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a R specific problem. You need to get your algorithm working correctly first. Compare the code you have written against what you want to do. If you need help with the algorithm then tag the question as such. Moreover the function call to Simulateinhomogeneousprocess is very inconsistent. Some insight into that function would help. What is that function returning, a number or a vector?

Within the loop you are increasing the value of n by at least 1 each time so you never reach the end.

```
newevent<-times[count] + Simulateinhomogeneousprocess(lambda2,tmax,lambdamax=NA)
```

This creates a non empty variable

```
times<-c(times,newevent)
```

Increases the "times" vector by at least 1 (since newevent is non-empty)

```
count<-count+1
n<-length(times)
```

You increase the count by 1 but also increase the n value by atleast 1 thus creating a never ending loop. One of these things has to change for the loop to stop.

Comment: Hello, Thanks everyone. The Simulateinhomogeneousprocess is a vector of events from an inhomogeneous process. @RohitDas; if I want to keep both the lines count<-count+1
n<-length(times)and want to run the loop for 15 times, can I write the condition within while as (count<15) ??